# Uncaught TypeError: X has no method 'Y' - but Y *is* declared

Tags: javascript

// Now answered - see line in code

I'm getting thrown an exception because supposedly the method I'm calling isn't declared. But actually it is, so I'm not sure why it's happening

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object #<Unit> has no method 'onLoopEvent'
```

And the code is

```
function Unit () {
     var item = new Item();
     item.onLoopEvent = function( index ) {
         ...
     }

     return item; // <--- WAS missing this - as pointed out first by ars265
}

items[ items.length ] = new Unit();

// main loop that gets called periodically
function onLoop () {
    for( var i=0; i < items.length ; i++ ) {
    var item = items[ i ];
    item.onLoopEvent( i );
    }
}
```

I can't see why this is happening. It looks like the method is declared correctly

Comment: No, really I don't think you are, you return nothing from Unit

Comment: `onLoopEvent` is a property of `item`, not your Unit instance, which is what `items[i]` is pointing to.

Comment: @ars265

That is indeed the answer -.- .
Faster than I could edit my title and save.
dargh!
I assumed that the error meant the object was fine and the method was missing. actually it meant both were missing. meh. 
If you made this an answer I'd accept it for you

Comment: @Timo, There you are. Have fun with your script. It's the little things that are the most annoying. ;)

Comment: @Timo, You have accepted a totally incorrect answer. Please see other's answers for more explanations and read about [OO in JavaScript](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Introduction_to_Object-Oriented_JavaScript).

Comment: I appreciate others think its incorrect, but I added the return line suggested and my program has sprung to life working correctly, so on the face of it, it fixes the issue - whether there's a technicality that's wrong I don't know but the thing runs now and before it just hung

Comment: @Timo, It's also good to understand why it fixed your issue and why the initially posted answer was incorrect or you will never make any progress. Additionnaly, your code also does have to make *sense* and reflect your domain as much as possible. If you return an instance of `Item` from the `Unit` constructor, ask yourself if you shouldn't simply do `new Item()`. Perhaps `item` should be a member of a `Unit` instance instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do to the fact that you are returning nothing from `new Unit()` you are setting the array index item to `undefined`, which is causing you're issue.

**Correction**
As corrected, you are not returning `undefined`, as that is what a function returns if no value is returned. Instead you are returning a new instance of the `Unit` function. That's what I get for eating and answering at the same time. ;)

Answer (score 0):

`new Unit()` returns a `Unit` instance, not an `Item` instance. The `items` array hold references to `Unit` instances only.

Here's what you could do:

```
function Unit () {
     this.item = new Item();
     this.item.onLoopEvent = function( index ) {
         ...
     }
}
```

Then in the loop:

```
// main loop that gets called periodically
function onLoop () {
    for( var i=0; i < items.length ; i++ ) {
    var unit = items[ i ];
    unit.item.onLoopEvent( i );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess you mean this:

```
var Item = function() {}
function Unit () {
     var item = new Item();
     item.onLoopEvent = function( index ) {
         console.log(index);
     }
     return item;
}
var items = [];
items[ items.length ] = Unit();

// main loop that gets called periodically
function onLoop () {
    for( var i=0; i < items.length ; i++ ) {
    var item = items[ i ];
    item.onLoopEvent( i );
    }
}
onLoop();
```

You should return something in Unit. Or if you don't return then you should use *this.item = new Item();* to attach something to the Unit function. Otherwise your newly created Item is leaving only in the Unit's scope.

Notice that I didn't use *new* infront of Unit. That's because I'm calling the function and not creating a new instance.

Answer (score 0):

```
function Unit() {
    this.onLoopEvent = function (index) {
        //...
    };
}

var items = [];
for (var i = 0; i < 5; ++i) items.push(new Unit());

function onLoop() {
    var i;
    for (i = 0; i < items.length; ++i) {
        items[i].onLoopEvent(i);
    }
}
```